# Removed '/bin/tempfile', now problems with X

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xorg, temp, xserver

I just undeliberately deleted my `bin/tempfile`, please don't ask why.
I experienced no issues, however, after a reboot, I wasn't able to login anymore. When I entered my password and pressed ENTER, I got a black screen, and 2 seconds later the login screen appeared again.

My system is **Kubuntu 17.10** on **4.14.11** Kernel.

I did some research on it, but I still got no clue what this file does, or how I can restore it (it was deleted by `rm`).

Until now I did the following:

- `touch /bin/tempfile`
- `chown root:root /bin/tempfile`
- `chmod 755 /bin/tempfile`

Finally I got back into KDE, and everything works fine this far, except an error, which I receive immediately after logging in: *Xsession: Xsession: Warning: unable to write to ; X session may exit*. The message is not in the style of my normal KDE desktop windows, it looks like a very old design, because the message probably comes from X itself. (I have no clue about this, sorry if it's rubbish)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Everything in `/bin` is some sort of program. Just creating an empty file named `/bin/tempfile` isn't going to solve anything, because your empty file doesn't *do* anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you can easily fix your issue by executing the following command:`sudo apt-get --reinstall install debianutils`.
Hope this helps.